# String.Empty, null, Length, or String.IsEmptyOrNull?

Tags: c#, string

Which way is really the fastest way to check for an empty string and there is any specific case where need to any specific.

```
1. String.IsNullOrEmpty()

2. str == null

3. str == null || str == String.Empty

4. str == null || str == ""

5. str == null || str.length == 0
```

Comment: The 1st one is the correct way. Because its inbuit in a string.

Comment: 'str' is not a good variable name

Comment: In most of those examples there is no difference. For example testing to see if the length is 0 is checking to see if its an empty string. In one example just checking to see if its null is sort of silly, since the default value for a string is an empty string, not a null string.  We are talking about performance differnces that you won't even begin to measure since they are so negligible.  Stop trying to optimized trivial tasks.

Comment: This is unlikely to make any difference. Better worry about `str == " "`.

Comment: @Ramhound What makes you think the default value for `string` is an empty string? `string` is a reference type, its default value is null.

Comment: `str` is not a good variable name. `s` is just fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use option 1.

If you specifically want to check for `null` or empty strings, then there's no reason to use anything other than `string.IsNullOrEmpty`. It's the canonical way of doing so in .NET, and any differences in performance will be almost certainly be negligible.

This is a textbook example of [premature optimization](http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/2011/05/03/the-perils-of-premature-optimization/); by all means, write *efficient* code, but don't waste development time over it for no justifiable gain in performance.  Remember that your time as a developer is generally **far** more valuable than the CPU's time.

Quoth Donald Knuth:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

If this level of micro-optimisation is genuinely necessary for your application, then you probably shouldn't be using .NET.

Answer (score 5):

Do you care about whitespace as well?

If whitespace is valid, use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`, otherwise use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` (in .Net 4.0 or higher).  The latter is equivalent to, but more performant than, `String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;`

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Found this website with some stats on the different methods: http://www.dotnetperls.com/empty-string

Answer (score 2):

The difference in speed will be unnoticable.

The correct way to do it is 1, because it is safest and best readable.

Answer (score 1):

`String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is very much readable and does/works as intended, would be glad to stick to that.

Do you really have an edge case scenario where its falling short then please add the same to the question which would make it more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty()
```

that is the best way on .NET .

Answer (score 0):

I personally always use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`. I don't really think they do anything special other than check if it's either `null` or empty, so it shouldn't be any slower than a hand-written check.

Besides, sometimes you might be in a hurry and accidentally put the `null` check at the end, getting a nasty surprise. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its better way and recomended to use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) for checking null or empty strings most rapidly. Because its inbuilt method in String.

Answer (score 0):

In your samples, the solution 2 is the fastest. But it is a solution different from the others, since it doesn't check if the string is empty.

Otherwise, given that you want to check if a string is null or empty, the solution 5 is the fastest. String.IsNullOrEmpty() does exactly the same thing as solution 5 but adds a function call (if it isn't inlined at runtime). Still, I would recommand the first solution:

1/ the performance penalty is negligible

2/ It's easier to read

3/ it's a built-in method, so it's future-proof

Comment: I have to downvote this answer because the default value of a string variable is an empty string not a null string.  Although everything you say about **String.IsNullOrEmpty** is correct.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Where do I talk about the default value of a string?

Comment: I made that point.  Which is a negative to your statement that solution 2 is the fastest, since it really does not appear to do what the author actually wants to test for, since it has limited uses.

Comment: Well that's why I precised "But it is a solution different from the others, since it doesn't check if the string is empty. "